# why linq orderby work with anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

In one project on .net 4.5.2 I have following LINQ:

```
var orderVolumes = _ordersRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(o => o.CreationDate >= startMonth)
            .GroupBy(o => new { o.CreationDate.Year, o.CreationDate.Month })
            .OrderBy(or => new { or.Key.Year, or.Key.Month })
            .Select(
                gr =>
                    new TempOrderVolume
                    {
                        Year = gr.Key.Year,
                        Month = gr.Key.Month,
                        NumberOfOrders = gr.Count(),
                        PriceOfOrders = gr.Sum(p => p.Price) ?? 0.0m
                    }).ToList();
```

`GetAll()` method returns `IQueryable<Order>`, `Order` class has `DateTime CreationDate` property.

I wrote a unit test for method that contains this code, I mocked repository, created a `List<Order> _orders`, added some data in this list, and setup for `GetAll()` method return `_orders.AsQueryable()`. 
Test failed with argument exception

> "At least one object must implement IComparable"

on OrderBy(...) step . 
I am not surprised that compiler doesn't know how to compare an anonymous objects `{ or.Key.Year, or.Key.Month }`

But I don't understand why it works in application itself?

please don't suggest me how to solve this exception, I know about possibility to do `OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)` and about using non-anonymous type implementing IComparable.

My question only - why this code works without exception when it looks like it shouldn't?

Comment: Well, the database can order by this anonymous type. The LINQ provider is able to produce SQL that works in the database. But in Linq-To-Objects this doesn't work. You would get the same exception above if you'd prepend `AsEnumerable()` before the `OrderBy`.

Comment: Specifically this is turned into SQL and since SQL just lists off the column to order on this can be translated easily.  However as you seem to already understand when done in code Linq needs to know how to compare the single item given and doesn't try to decompose an anonymous type into its parts.  There are a number of things that will only work with EF or Line-To-SQL and stuff that will only work with Linq-to-Objects.

Comment: Just a quick side note this is precisely why you don't expose IQueryable in your repository.

Comment: @FilipCordas How so?  Why is it a problem for someone to write code like this that works properly and does something useful?  The only problem here is that the unit test was written using something that has less functionality than the thing it's mocking.

Comment: @Sevy Well that is the problem you won't be able to mock IQueryable it's such a complex abstraction even EF can't [implement it](http://codetunnel.com/should-you-return-iqueryablet-from-your-repositories/).